# StringFromGUID2 under 64 bit Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I was previously using:

```
Public Declare Function StringFromGUID2 Lib "ole32.dll" _
    (rclsid As GUID, ByVal lpsz As Long, ByVal cbMax As Long) As Long
```

under Access 2007 on both 32 bit and 64 bit Windows to generate GUIDs for me.

Where GUID Is defined as:

```
Public Type GUID
Data1 As Long
Data2 As Integer
Data3 As Integer
Data4(7) As Byte
End Type
```

(since VT_GUID wasn't supported in VBA for variants)

I've now got a new machine that is set up with Access 2010 64 bit and this stuff is now broken.

What is the equivalent code to do this under Access 2010 64 bit?

I have added the PtrSafe attribute as required:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function StringFromGUID2 Lib "ole32.dll" _
    (rclsid As GUID, ByVal lpsz As Long, ByVal cbMax As Long) As Long
```

This causes a type mismatch at the actual call:

```
Dim rc As Long
Dim stGuid As String
' 39 chars  for the GUID plus room for the Null char
stGuid = String$(40, vbNullChar)
rc = StringFromGUID2(rclsid, StrPtr(stGuid), Len(stGuid) - 1)
```

Which is to be expected since StrPtr will return a LongPtr on 64 bit and a Long on 32 bit systems.

I'm not a full-time developer so I'm not sure what is the most appropriate way to create GUID strings in a way that will work on both 32 and 64 bit systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StringFromGUID is available to the Access application.

[Application.StringFromGUID Method (Access)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193935.aspx)

You can even use it in queries.

Comment: Hi Remou,  how do I define the GUID?  If I use the definition of GUID I was previously using, I get an error message about coercion: "Only user-defined types defined in object modules can be coerced to or from variant or passed to late-bound functions.

Comment: I am not at all sure what you are doing, but see if this is of interest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172214(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: The bit you are not sure of is that I have to generate GUIDS, not just read them.  All the examples I've seen basically use controls which have GUIDs already ion them.  I need to generate new GUIDs.

Comment: To do this I use the CoCreateGUID function: Public Declare PtrSafe Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32.dll" _
    (vCLSID As GUID) As Long
  which needs a GUID defined as in the original post (as a user defined type)

Comment: I used this code http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176790 in Access 2010 x64 and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks Remou,  I ammended the code to provide the Canonical form of the GUID (end braces and intervening hyphens).

Comment: I saw this code (support.microsoft.com/kb/176790) earlier but somehow didn't register that it would work.